# &amp; doesn't work as expected in URL

Tags: php, url, web

I have this URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/TrackEmail?j=eyJ1IjoiMzdDOC42MS4wLjE0OCJ9&amp;r=0.569019181653857.gif
```

I'm interested in this part `&amp;r=0.5...`. This `&amp;` is encoded `&` symbol so that it doesn't gets interpreted as params separator. So I would assume that `j` param has the value of `eyJ1IjoiMzdDOC42MS4wLjE0OCJ9&amp;r=0.569019181653857.gif`. However, when I output `j` param value `$_REQUEST['j']` it only shows the part before the `&amp;` - `eyJ1IjoiMzdDOC42MS4wLjE0OCJ9`. Why so?

And what is `r=0.5...`? I can't access it like this `$_REQUEST['r']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm interested in this part `&amp;r=0.5`. This `&amp;` is encoded `&` symbol so that it doesn't gets interpreted as params separator.

`&amp;` has no special meaning in a URI. In *HTML*, it represents an `&` that isn't the start of a character reference.

If you want to encode an `&` for a URI (which doesn't appear to be the intention for this code) then you need to use URI encoding: `%26`

> And what is `r=0.5`...? I can't access it like this `$_REQUEST['r']`.

If that URI appears in HTML and unless it is overwritten by a cookie or post data (I don't have the precedence order for `$_REQUEST` memorised), you *should* be able to.

If, however, you are pasting the HTML representation of the URI into the address bar of a browser (or otherwise fetching it **without parsing it as HTML**) then the data will appear in `$_REQUEST['amp;r']` instead of `$_REQUEST['r']`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! It indeed got interperted when pasted into browser as `$_REQUEST['amp;r']`. This URL is inserted into HTML body of an email, so probably this part `&amp;r` gets transformed into `&r` when requested by browser, right?

Comment: You can't make the browser interpret a URL placed into the address bar as HTML, it isn't a place that HTML belongs. And wrong, it gets transformed into `&r` when the email client's HTML parser parses the email. The browser will never see the HTML version (which is only handled by the email client).

Comment: So I don't understand why they put `&amp;` into the URL instead of simple `&`? I just pasted the URL with `&amp;` and with `&` as image source into HTML page and the server correctly interpreted both params `j` and `r` in both cases.

Comment: Any ideas re my question in my previous comment?

Comment: Because it is an HTML representation of a URL, not a plain text representation. If you use `&` instead of `&amp;` then, in this particular case, it works, but that is error recovery on the part of the HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

`&amp;` is a HTML or XML encoding, not a URL encoding.

You need to use `%26` instead to insert an ampersand into a URL that isn't part of a query parameter.